# Comparing a String against values in a List<Integer>

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, contains

I have two values, 5 and 6, both of which are Integers, that are part of an ArrayList.  I also have another boolean method that has a String input, and I am having to compare the value of that String and go through that list and see if that value matches an element in that list.  If it does match, then I should return true, else false.  The goal is to see if my value matches one of the values in the list.
The list is part of a constants class, and I have my method in a Validator class.  Below is my code:

Constants.java:

```
public static final List<Integer> TYPES = new ArrayList<Integer> (Arrays.asList(5,6));
```

Validator.java:

```
public static boolean isPromoTypeFormatValid (String value) {
    value = Util.getTrimmedValue(value);
    int intValue = Integer.valueOf(value);
    List <Integer> promoTypeList = scpduuConstants.PROMO_TYPES;
    for(int i = 0; i < promoTypeList.size(); i++) {
        if (promoTypeList.contains(intValue)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, and would I get an issue when comparing the String value against the ArrayList value when it is an Integer?  I'm a little new to this but trying to figure out the most efficient way possible.  Please let me know for any suggestions.

Comment: `typesList.contains(value)` is working on incompatible types based on your code.. the compiler won't complain, but the comparison shall fail.

Comment: Contains uses the `equals` method. A string will never be equal to an integer you first need to convert the string to an integer using `Integer.valueof`

Comment: @oleg noted!  I have modified the post to show that.  I'm just wondering what the efficiency is of having the String value trimmed, then set another variable that holds the int value of that string using the Integer.valueOf() method, and then looping through the list to see if my new intValue is contained in the list.  Any way to clean that up?

Comment: Your code will work like that. But you should check whether `Integer.valueOf()` throws a `NumberFormatException`. I think in that case you would like to return `false`, too?

Comment: The loop is not needed if `contains` method is used to check if the `intValue` is in the list; if the value is not in the list, redundant invocations will occur several times.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps a bit:

```
public static final List<Integer> TYPES = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 6));

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String value = "5";

    checkValue(value);

}

public static boolean checkValue(String value) {

    final var valueAsInt = Integer.parseInt(value.trim());
    
    return TYPES.contains(valueAsInt);

}
```